# libGDX: Adding multiple TextButton in table

Tags: libgdx

When I'm adding the same TextButton multiple times in my table, only the last one will be displayed:

```
public void show(){
    button = new TextButton("Hello", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button);

    final Table table = new Table();
    table.add(button);
    table.row();
    table.add(button);
    table.row();
    table.add(button);
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.debug();
    stage.addActor(table);
}

public void render(float delta) {
    stage.act();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.draw();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addActor(actor)` method called when you're adding a `Actor` to table by using `add(..)`.

because `Table` is inherently a `Group` and according to doc :

When we call `addActor(actor)` method of Group

> Adds an actor as a child of that group, removing it from its previous
>   parent. If the actor is already a child of that group, no changes are
>   made.

so create different object of required `Actor` and add them on table.